# Which is the best way to track changes in an array inside a component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

When creating a custom component in Angular 7, which is the best way to track changes in an array?

Example:

```
export class Test {
   @Input() myArray = []

 // tell if array was modified (push, pop, reassigned...)
}
```

Also, is there a better way to do this (like observables, etc)? Why?

Comment: Do you just want to run a function each time it's changed? the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle method might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think ngOnChanges tracks the array reference . It works if I do something like 
 `array = [ 'test' ].concat(array)` but not if I do a simple `array.push('test');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using `ngOnChanges()` which is one of the Angular lifecycle hook. Where you can find information like:

1. If it is the first change.
2. What's the current value.
3. What's the previous value.

It is of type : [SimpleChange](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange)

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
 // Detect Changes
  let myArrayChange = changes['myArray'];
  let currentValue = myArrayChange.currentValue;
  let previousValue = myArrayChange.previousValue;
}
```

**Also, Angular change detection only checks object identity, not object content, so push, pop are not detected.** So what you can do is in the Child Component  where you are assigning this input, while pushing, push different object by using `slice()` method of `Array`

**Child Component HTML:**

```
<test myArray="arr"></test>
```

**Child Component TS:**

```
export class Child{

    arr: any = [];

    someMethod(){
        this.arr.push('new element');
        this.arr = this.arr.slice();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think ngOnChanges tracks the array reference . It works if I do something like 
`array = [ 'test' ].concat(array)`
but not if I do a simple 
`array.push('test');`

Comment: `push()` followed by `slice()` should work.

Comment: Or: `this.arr = [...this.arr, 'new element']` would work too. It'd create a new array.